# read values of reference direct by std::pair<std::array<std::array<u_int16_t,2>,1>,std::string>>

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair

can someone tell me how to access the individual values directly?
To really use the referent of out and not store in the temporary variable PosTextfield and val between.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

using Cursor_matrix = std::array<std::array<uint16_t,2>, 1>;

void foo(const std::pair<Cursor_matrix,std::string> &out)
{
  Cursor_matrix PosTextfield;
  PosTextfield = std::get<0>(out);

  std::string val = std::get<1>(out);

  std::cout << PosTextfield[0][0] << PosTextfield[0][1] << val << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Cursor_matrix pos;
    pos[0][0] = 1;
    pos[0][1] = 2;

    std::string str = "hello";

    std::pair<Cursor_matrix, std::string> pos_text;

    pos_text = std::make_pair(pos, str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the values stored in `pos_text`'s `CursorMatrix`?

Comment: Yes this one by one, but also the string element so you could call e.g. the method c_str()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::get` returns references. You can just store these references:

```
const auto& PosTextfield = std::get<0>(out);
const auto& val = std::get<1>(out);
```

or

```
const auto& PosTextfield = out.first;
const auto& val = out.second;
```

or you can replace the `auto` keywords with the actual types if you prefer. `const` can be removed as well, since `auto` will deduce it, but writing it explicitly makes it clear to the reader that the two references are non-modifiable.

This doesn't create any new objects. The references refer to the elements of the pair passed to the function.

Or just refer to the element directly where you want to use them with `out.first` and `out.second` or `std::get<0>(out)` and `std::get<1>(out)`.

Comment: `const auto &`?

Comment: @PaulSanders `const` should be deduced, but can be added explicitly to make it clear that the variables are non-modifiable.

Comment: Ok, and how it is possible to access the specific fields of the std::array with the help of <get(0)get(0>> or how?

Comment: @zombieanfuehrer Exactly as you are doing right now. With the references I defined above `PosTextfield[0][0]` is the element inside the passed object.

Answer (score 2):

You can access a `std::pair`'s elements by the following:

```
pos_text.first; // Returns CursorMatrix
pos_text.second; // Returns std::string
```

So you can rewrite `foo()` as:

```
void foo(const std::pair<Cursor_matrix, std::string>& out)
{
    std::cout << out.first[0][0] << out.first[0][1] << out.second << "\n";
}
```